# Concat different tables?

Tags: mysql

I need to concatenate from two different tables.

Compare `s.panelid` (result like "AA") to `b.modulecodes` and return number_of_strings. Then put `s.panelid` (result  like "AA") and `number_of_string` together.

```
select concat(Mid(s.panelid, 5, 2), ' - ' , '??') as `Module Type-Strings`
from r2rtool.stringtopanel s, be.modulecodes b 
where s.insertts > '2011-07-15' and s.insertts < '2011-07-26' and Mid(s.panelid, 5, 2) != 99
group by date(insertts), `Module Type-Strings`
order by `Module Type-Strings`;
```

`Be` (Table): modulecodes, number_of_strings

- AA - 12
- AB - 4
- AD - 3
- AE - 12

When I run the above query it returns things like: `Module Type-Strings` = 'AA-??'  and "AB-??" of course.

I am looking for: `Module Type-Strings` = 'AA-12'

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you haven't tried it already...

Have you tried this?

```
select concat(Mid(s.panelid, 5, 2), ' - ' , b.number_of_string) as `Module Type-Strings`
from r2rtool.stringtopanel s, be.modulecodes b 
where s.insertts > '2011-07-15' and s.insertts < '2011-07-26' and Mid(s.panelid, 5, 2) != 99
group by date(insertts), `Module Type-Strings`
order by `Module Type-Strings`;
```

There I'm basically replacing the '??' with the column you are asking about, number_of_string in the be.modulecodes table (aliased as b in the from clause).

Comment: I have to get b.number_of_strings based on s.panelid -> b.modulecodes.